# altering headwidth in latex w/out fancyhdr

Tags: header, latex

i´m having trouble getting my style done in latex.

here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}   
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\lefoot[LE]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2cm][l]{\thepage}}}
\rofoot[RO]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[2cm][r]{\thepage}}}
\usepackage[]{setspace}
\usepackage{showframe}
\setlength{\textheight}{20cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{13cm}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{section test2}
\lipsum[3-10]
\end{document}
```

i would like to have the header to be streched out on the outer side up to the pagenumber, so the header and the pagenumber are justified. i seem not to be able to get that working. 
thanks,
fleischfressende

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the chapter number/title via `\leftmark` and the section number/title via `\rightmark`. Then just use the same notation and box manipulation you used for the footers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\lefoot{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2cm][l]{\thepage}}}
\rofoot{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[2cm][r]{\thepage}}}
\lehead{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2cm][l]{\leftmark}}}
\rohead{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[2cm][r]{\rightmark}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter test}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{section test2}
\lipsum[3-10]

\end{document}
```

While a `2cm` box is too small for the header content, it doesn't really matter, as you're just interested in the specific placement/alignment.